# What do the two numbers listed next to users names mean in the tag stats screen?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

When viewing tag stats on stackoverflow.com, users have to numbers listed next to their name.  The one on the left is light gray and the one on the right is dark gray.  The one on the left appears to be the number of answers, questions, etc based on the category heading.  What's the second number?

[alt text http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/7773/graynumbers.png](http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/7773/graynumbers.png)

Answer (score 5):

The dark one says how many answers the user has made in that particular tag; the light grey one says how many upvotes they received for them.

If you hover your cursor over the number, you get this information as a tooltip.

[celebrating my 3k rep, here're my first freehand circle http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/4777/92596591.png](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/4777/92596591.png)

Comment: It was in the tooltip the whole time, thanks!

Comment: Aaahh! Drop shadows! But nice art :)